# How to Switch Scenes Based on MUI Slider Selection Using Three.js React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, three.js, event-handling, state

Preface: I am fairly new to using React.js and Three.js

Scenario: Using Three.js to render a whole building (GLB files) hoping to be able to change to different rooms within that building using an MUI Slider in React. As I drag the slider, I would like the scenes to change.

What I have done so far: I have my Three.js in a useEffect() for my React code similar to this: [Using Three.js with React](https://dev.to/omher/how-to-start-using-react-and-threejs-in-a-few-minutes-2h6g). I have created several scenes within Three.js and can switch between them using a button. I set the MUI Slider up so that an onChange or OnChangeCommitted event occurs, I set a variable with the value of the MUI Slider (0, 25, 50 for example).

I am using a renderer.domElement.addEventListener ([similar to this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-capture-mouse-dblclick-event-in-renderer/32774)) to execute a function when I click within the Three.js section (temporary solution - I need to find a better way) to execute a function that performs a few checks such as the current scene and the MUI Slider state value that was set. This successfully allows me to switch scenes back and forth but requires extra input from the user. I am hoping to make it smoother so when I simply change the slider, it will change the scene without needing an extra click.

I have also tried using document.getElementById("id-of-slider").addEventListener("click", function()) to get the id of the MUI Slider and when a value is clicked, to run the same function described above to check the changed or committed value of the MUI Slider and based on some checks, to set the scene. This has not worked for me so far and am unsure why because the same function works when I use the renderer.domElement approach.

The MUI Slider was not specifically intended to do something like this as far as I'm aware. For our use case, this functionality would greatly enhance the UX if we are able to smoothly switch scenes with a slider without any additional inputs from the user like the extra click that currently has to be done. I appreciate any constructive feedback you may have.